# css div image information for search engines

Tags: css, image, html, search-engine, information-retrieval

I have a website and in the main page a I have a div with an image where with a very nice design says "contact us by calling 1 800 blabla..". so I was thinking if the only place where the phone number of my company, is on a div with an image background, how the search engines are going to recognize or find my company's number,

so my question is basically how can I add information to this div which is :

```
<div id="phone"></div>
```

and any other div that i need to put information for robots and stuff

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to use this approach

```
#ContactInformation {/* your image and restof padding */}
#ContactInformation h2 { display: none; visibility: hidden; }

<div id="ContactInformation">
    <h2>Phone:</h2>
    <label>1 800 blah blah</label>
</div>
```

Actually Search Engines See and check `h2` tag and it's value but your user wont see the **h2** text.

Comment: The only problem is that the FIR technique is bad for accessibility :)

Comment: "The LABEL element may be used to attach information to controls. Each LABEL element is associated with exactly one form control." See here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1

Comment: @Wabbitseason, I knew it and that was why I suggest this approach. Actually Search Engines face with a div that consists of a **header** and a **label** and because of the limited area of the **div** it will associate label to h2. this is what exactly `GMO` islooking for. isn't it?

Comment: @Nasser Hadjloo, yes it is, i mean if you say that will make search engones or robots to read it, its fine, another question is, what the difference of this and just using a SPAN tag instead of h2 and label?
you also say something about the limited area, but since is display none, wont be a problem? (im guessing), thank you for your help!

Comment: @Gmo, when Search engines face with `<div>` they look for the closing tag to speculate what would be inside, (you have a limited (small) area, that consist of 2 element `<h2>` which tell this is an important text and a `lebel` that associate with `h2`. if you use `span` instead of `h2` then your phone number will get a minor importance in Search engines view.

Comment: @Nasser Hadjloo, idk why, but is not working, the info is displaying on top of the div =/

Comment: @nasser hadjloo, do i need to add #Contact Information label {display:none; visibility:hidden;} ????

Comment: @GMO no, you don't need to make div invisible.  Actually You have to set your image in div backgorund.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy using an image replacement technique.

```
<div id="phone"><span>11-1111-1111</span></div>
```

And the CSS.
(change your phone div to be whatever you need it to be, but you'll need to define a width and overflow: hidden to hide the text.

```
#phone
{
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#phone span
{
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
}
```

Alternatively, without using extra markup (I read somewhere that google disapproved of using text-indent in this way which is why I didn't use this first, but I can't find the source for that).

```
<div id="phone">11-1111-1111</div>
```

And the CSS.

```
#phone
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -999em;
}
```

Additionally: http://css-tricks.com/css-image-replacement/ looks like a fairly decent resource.

Comment: I tried the frist option and is not working =/, I added the overflow:hidden, widht i had it already, but is not wokring, i mean is not dissappearing.

Comment: I changed left: -999em for visibiliy:hidden;, and it works alright, now id like to know if this will allow google robots or others to find this.

Comment: @Gmo It will, but it's not accessible. Read the link I provided for more information about the various types of image replacement and why FIR is sub-optimal.

Comment: @Gmo I didn't look into my CSS too deeply, but without the position absolute it wont hide itself. Read the link anyway, and have a look through there to find the best option for your particular case.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [hCard microformat specification](http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard) and create an HTML code something like this:

```
<div class="call-us vcard">
    <span class="tel">
        <span class="type">business</span>
        <span class="value">+1.800.blabla</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Where the `call-us` classname formats the div by setting its dimensions, visually hiding the `span.tel` tag and adding the image as a background. Search engines would recognize that this is a contact card (note the `vcard` classname), and they would correctly parse the phone number.